# Relation between the Ideal gas constant and Boltzmann's constant

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

If $R=N_A\cdot k_B$ how can the following equation be true as well?

$$\frac{R}{M}=\frac{k_B}{m}$$

That would result in: $R=\frac{1}{n}\cdot k_B$, which is different from the first equation.

Comment: How can it be checked if the definition of $M$ and $m$ are not given ?

Comment: @FredericThomas I'm sorry: $m$ is the mass and $M$ is the molar mass; $n$ is the chemical amount.

Comment: And $N_{A}$ is Avogadro's number.

Answer (score 2):

> How can it be checked if the definition of M and m are not given ?

– @Frederic Thomas

Indeed.
You posit,
$$
R=N_{A}k_{B}
$$
and then, you posit,
$$
R=\frac{M}{m}k_{B}
$$
This only makes sense --I'm assuming the whole of chemistry and statistical physics makes sense--, if,
$$
mN_{A}=M
$$
So you *must* mean,
$$
M=\textrm{mass of your 1-mole sample}
$$
$$
m=\textrm{molecular mass of your microscopic species}
$$

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying what everything was: $m$ is the mass and $M$ is the molar mass, as you correctly guessed. $n$ is the chemical amount and $N_{A}$ is Avogadro's number. The problem is $mN_{A}=M$ is not true, right? This is true instead: $mn=M$. How can that be?

Comment: @PedroNogueira : You have to be careful with the notation. $m$ is the mass of what? In this answer it was shown that $m$ has to be the mass of a particle, and not the total mass. The total mass here is $m_T = N\, m$. You can relate the number of particles with the Avogrado constant and the amount of substance.

Comment: I have now come to realize that. That's the answer I was looking for. I just got it myself a minute ago.